# Foregin Key problems android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to ask what is the problem in my code that my foregin key is not working. Primary key is working well. 
I have 3 table, created in this way: (some words can be in polish, cause I am doing it to pass subject but these words are not importnat( I guess))

```
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "Kontrahenci";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "imie";
private static final String KEY_SURNAME = "nazwisko";
private static final String KEY_STREET = "ulica";
private static final String KEY_NRB = "numerBudynku";
private static final String KEY_NRL = "numerLokalu";
private static final String KEY_KOD = "KodPocztowy";
private static final String KEY_CITY = "Miejscowosc";
private static final String KEY_NIP = "NIP";
private static final String KEY_TEL = "Telefon";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";


private static final String</b> DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " 
+ TABLE_CONTACTS + " ( " 
        + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
+ KEY_NAME +" TEXT, " 
+ KEY_SURNAME+" TEXT, "  
+KEY_STREET+" TEXT, " 
+KEY_NRB+" INT(4), " 
+KEY_NRL+" INTEGER(4), " 
+KEY_KOD+" INTEGER(5), " 
+KEY_CITY+" TEXT, " 
+KEY_NIP + " TEXT, " 
+ KEY_TEL+" TEXT, " 
+KEY_EMAIL+" TEXT "+" ); ";



 private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS= "Produkty"; 
private static final String KEY_IDPROD = "id"; 
private static final String KEY_NAMEPROD = "nazwa"; 
private static final String KEY_IMG = "obraz"; 
private static final String KEY_PRICE = "CENA"; 
 private static final String  DATABASE_PRODUCTS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "  
+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + " ( "  
        + KEY_IDPROD +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
+ KEY_NAMEPROD +" TEXT, " 
+ KEY_IMG+" NUMBER, "  
+KEY_PRICE+" REAL" + " ); "; 

private static final String TABLE_ORDER = "Zamowienia"; 
private static final String KEY_IDORD = "id"; 
private static final String KEY_ID1  = "id_kon"; 
private static final String KEY_ID2 = "id_prod"; 
private static final String KEY_ILOSC = "ilosc"; 
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "Status"; 

 private static final String DATABASE_ORDERS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDER + " ( " 
+ KEY_IDORD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "  
+ KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER, " 
+ KEY_ID2 +" INTEGER, " 
+ KEY_ILOSC + " INTEGER, " 
        + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT, " 
+"FOREIGN KEY (id_kon) REFERENCES "+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"(id), "  
+"FOREIGN KEY (id_prod) REFERENCES " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +"(id));" ; 




public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
 db.execSQL(DATABASE_PRODUCTS_CREATE);
 db.execSQL(DATABASE_ORDERS_CREATE);

 if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
  }
}
```

Later I insert data to all in this way:

```
public void addProdukt (Produkt produkt){ 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(KEY_NAMEPROD, produkt.getnazwa()); 
    values.put(KEY_IMG, produkt.getZdj()); 
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, produkt.getCena()); 
db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values); 
db.close();} 


 public void addZamow (Zamowienie zamowienie){ 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(KEY_ID1, zamowienie.getIDk()); 
    values.put(KEY_ID2, zamowienie.getIDp()); 
    values.put(KEY_ILOSC, zamowienie.getIlosc()); 
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, zamowienie.getStatus()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_ORDER, null, values); 
    db.close(); 
}
```

All tables without `FOREIGN KEY` are working fine, but this one with, when I want to get all data is showing me "Source not found". I am adding this key from Spinners by updating `Integer values` and later applying to tabel by push button, but even if I put manually as that

```
db.addZamow(new Zamowienie(1,1,x,tstatus));
```

I still have this mistake. To get all List of these elements I am using this function:

```
public List<Zamowienie> getAllZamowienie(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    List<Zamowienie> zamowlist = new ArrayList<Zamowienie>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ORDER;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Zamowienie zamow = new Zamowienie();
            zamow.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            zamow.setIDk(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            zamow.setIDp(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            zamow.setIlosc(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            zamow.setStatus(cursor.getString(4));

            zamowlist.add(zamow);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return zamowlist;   
}
```

Mistake appears after this line :`zamow.setIDk(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));`

Do you have any idea how can I make it works? Thank You in advance for answers.

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors, also you should use `cursor.getInt()` rather than `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString())`.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"` -is my LogCat error, and other one mistake is about this line I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
```

You have null values in your database... You can prevent this from happening in the future by setting up your table with `default` values:  `+ KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "`. To correct the data in your current table use an `UPDATE` command to change all null values to an appropriate `default` value.

The alternative is to check *each* value *every* time:

```
String value = cursor.getString(1);
if(value != null)
    zamow.setIDk(Integer.parseInt(value));
```

But that is the *slowest* way to fix your problem.
Again if you use the appropriate method, `getInt()`:

```
zamow.setIDk(cursor.getInt(1));
```

You might not have this problem...